# Why isn't my reducer updating my store?

Tags: redux, immutability

I am new to redux and I am trying to create a solely redux app. The problem I am having is that my reducer won't update my store. If I were to mutate the store in the reducer then I would see my change. I know that is bad practice, so I am trying to update it without mutating it, but when I look at the console. I am seeing no change to the state. Can someone help me figure out why the reducer isn't updating the store?

This is my action:

```
store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log("store changed", store.getState());
});
```

Here is my reducer:

```
const fruitReducer = function(state={
  fruits: [
    {
      "itemName": "banana",
      "price": 1.00,
      "quantityRemaining": 10
    },
    {
      "itemName": "apple",
      "price": 2.00,
      "quantityRemaining": 5
    },
    {
      "itemName": "raspberry",
      "price": 5.00,
      "quantityRemaining": 2
    },
    {
      "itemName": "kiwi",
      "price": 3.00,
      "quantityRemaining": 15
    },
    {
      "itemName": "pineapple,
      "price": 7.00,
      "quantityRemaining": 1
    },
    {
      "itemName": "strawberries",
      "price": 2.00,
      "quantityRemaining": 3
    }
  ]
}, action){
  if(action.type === "DEDUCT"){
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      fruits: state.fruits.map((fruit, index) => {
        action.payload.map((actionFruit) => {
          if(fruit.itemName === actionFruit.itemName){
            let newQuantity = fruit.quantityRemaining - actionFruit.quantityRemaining;
            return Object.assign({}, fruit, {
              quantityRemaining: newQuantity
            });
          }
        });
        return fruit;
      })
    });
  }
  else
    return state;
}
```

Below is an example of my dispatchers(I created two doing the same thing):

```
store.dispatch({type: "DEDUCT", payload: [
  {
    "itemName": "banana",
    "quantityRemaining": 1
  },
  {
    "itemName": "apple",
    "quantityRemaining": 1
  },
  {
    "itemName": "strawberries",
    "quantityRemaining": 1
  }
]});
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see is that you're not actually returning the result of `action.fruits.map()`.  Arrow functions allow you to omit the `return` keyword if you don't use curly braces, but once you add curlies, you've started the body of a function just like normal, and it's up to you to explicitly return something.

Also, as a stylistic note, I'd suggest defining the initial state for that reducer as a separate variable:

```
const initialState = [ /* fruits here */];

const fruitReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    // reducer logic here
}
```

It looks like your nested update logic is on the right track, but you may want to read through the [Structuring Reducers - Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) section of the Redux docs as well.

Comment: So would I return `actionFruit`, before the closing brace on `action.fruits.map()`? I tried that and the reducer is still not updating the state.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this *can* happen by the way you compose your middleware.  For instance,  I previously had:

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware),
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
)
```

However, it seems as though the double apply middleware made redux grumpy, and it wouldn't catch new state updates from the rootReducer, just the epicMiddleware (which is a fancy thing to trigger actions/reducers from side effects).

Moving my `epicMiddleware` into my `applyMiddleware(...middleware)` call resolved the issues.  That is, updating to the following worked:

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware)) // epicMiddleware is now in the `middleware` array
)
```

It may not be your problem, but it is one thing that can cause your described symptom.